# I want to use filter() Operator to remove an element, but have a trouble to pass altered list as a new list?

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs

I've stuck to the problem when i was trying to remove element using Filter() operator. I want to pass altered list as a new one, but don't get how. any Ideas?

My Service.ts Code:

```
export class TaskServiceService {

  constructor() { }
  getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return of(TASKS);
  }
  filterTasks(task: Task):Observable<Task[]>{
    let filteredTasks = TASKS.filter(t => t.name !== task.name);
    return of(filteredTasks);
  }
}
```

This is my Component.ts file, where i want to pass list from dummy data:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getTasks();
  }

  deleteTask(task : Task){
     this.taskService.filterTasks(task)
    .subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks);
  }
```

And a snippet from Component.html file:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deleteTask(task)">x</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use Observables and subscriptions? Seems totally overkill and complicated to me. It's only about removing one item in a simple array, isn't it?

Assuming your `task` interface has an `id` field :

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deleteTask(task)">x</button>

deleteTask(task : Task){
     this.tasks = this.tasks.filter( t => t.id !== task.id )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intention correctly, I don't think the the `filter()` operator is the best way to solve your problem.

It looks like you are maintaining a collection of items, and need to remove one from the collection.  I assume that you would want this change to affect all potential consumers (not just the one calling `deleteTask()`).

If this is the case, the easiest way is to manage the state of the collection in your service, and have the `deleteTask()` methods modify that internal collection.  Then push the updated collection through a public observable.

Also, instead of using a method for getting tasks, you can simplify and just assign an observable.  It can also make the flow of data easier to follow if your methods only return `void` instead of values, and consumers only read data from the exposed public observable.

```
export class TaskServiceService {
  private _tasks: Task[] = []; // internal state of collection
  private tasks = new BehaviorSubject(this._tasks);
  public tasks$: Observable<Task[]> = this.tasks.asObservable();

  deleteTask(task: Task) {
    let filteredTasks = this._tasks.filter(t => t.name !== task.name);
    this.tasks.next(this._tasks = filteredTasks);
  }
}
```

Then in your component, you can simplify even further by

- eliminating `ngOnInit`
- eliminating local `this.tasks` variable (so component no longer maintains state, but rather the service does)
- leverage `async` pipe in the template, rather than subscribing in the controller

```
  public tasks$ = this.taskService.tasks$;

  deleteTask(task : Task){
     this.taskService.deleteTask(task);
  }
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let task of tasks$ | async">
    {{ task.name }}
    <button (click)="deleteTask(task)">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66030763?file=src/app/task-service.service.ts) example.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, it sounds pretty much close to my intention. I wanted to get exactly same result, as you did, by using "async pipe" and "Subject" from rxjs. So, it's done.

Comment: great! glad it helped :-)